# float not working in mysql database

Tags: php, database, floating-point, compare

i am using $_GET['var'] to get a variable then compare it with a variable in my database. the variable is 1.1 the var is set to "float" on the database so i know it can handle decimals but when i compare them with the code below i get nothing.

```
include 'connect.php';

$sql=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM table WHERE stuff='$stuff'"); 

while ($row=mysql_fetch_assoc($sql)) { 

$start=$row['start'];

}

echo $start; //nothing happens
```

Comment: 1) use `var_dump()` instead 2) probably there are no any rows that satisfy `where` condition

Comment: try to use `mysql_error()` just before the while loop to see if there are any errors.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

From what I know `float` type isn't precise. It doesn't show you that actual value so `1.1` that you saved may not be the actual value stored. Trying setting your field as `decimal` and give it a length of say, `10,1` where 10 is the maximum number of digits (the precision) and 1 is the number of digits to the right of the decimal point (the scale). It should work doing query like `stuff='1.1'` or `stuff=1.1`.

Comment: thank you very much.   this was the solution.  you guys were all very helpful and really quick to answer.  thanks a lot!

Answer (score 2):

`WHERE stuff = '$stuff'` is a String comparison.

Compare number like so

```
WHERE stuff = $stuff
```

Comment: post a little more information for us to help you further. For example, What happens when you run the query directly in MySQL?

Comment: There is nothing wrong in using quotes. It still should work properly (it does not compare strings, it converts the value in quotes to number and compare numbers)

Answer (score 2):

Don't use `float`( even if you insert 1.1 into the table, the actual value for float type is not 1.1, but something like 1.100000023841858) . Change it to `double` in database (or decimal)

Answer (score 0):

Change the stuff field to DOUBLE type.
Then,

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE stuff=$stuff
```

this should be the sql query

Answer (score 0):

You might not be seeing any output because your echo is outside the loop.

The scope of your variable $start would be confined to the loop.